# High ping to local router over WiFi

Tags: wireless

I've noticed that there are similar questions in this topic. but the solutions don't solve my problem...

ping local router reports:

```
64 bytes from 192.168.0.1: icmp_seq=16 ttl=64 time=1.06 ms
64 bytes from 192.168.0.1: icmp_seq=17 ttl=64 time=200 ms
64 bytes from 192.168.0.1: icmp_seq=20 ttl=64 time=210 ms
64 bytes from 192.168.0.1: icmp_seq=21 ttl=64 time=10.5 ms
64 bytes from 192.168.0.1: icmp_seq=22 ttl=64 time=1.41 ms
64 bytes from 192.168.0.1: icmp_seq=23 ttl=64 time=4.32 ms
64 bytes from 192.168.0.1: icmp_seq=24 ttl=64 time=1.58 ms
64 bytes from 192.168.0.1: icmp_seq=25 ttl=64 time=1.89 ms
64 bytes from 192.168.0.1: icmp_seq=26 ttl=64 time=1.35 ms
64 bytes from 192.168.0.1: icmp_seq=27 ttl=64 time=7.52 ms
64 bytes from 192.168.0.1: icmp_seq=28 ttl=64 time=1.52 ms
64 bytes from 192.168.0.1: icmp_seq=29 ttl=64 time=56.1 ms
64 bytes from 192.168.0.1: icmp_seq=30 ttl=64 time=147 ms
64 bytes from 192.168.0.1: icmp_seq=31 ttl=64 time=20567 ms
64 bytes from 192.168.0.1: icmp_seq=32 ttl=64 time=19770 ms
64 bytes from 192.168.0.1: icmp_seq=33 ttl=64 time=18786 ms
64 bytes from 192.168.0.1: icmp_seq=37 ttl=64 time=14728 ms
64 bytes from 192.168.0.1: icmp_seq=39 ttl=64 time=12690 ms
64 bytes from 192.168.0.1: icmp_seq=40 ttl=64 time=11676 ms
64 bytes from 192.168.0.1: icmp_seq=42 ttl=64 time=9731 ms
64 bytes from 192.168.0.1: icmp_seq=43 ttl=64 time=9613 ms
64 bytes from 192.168.0.1: icmp_seq=46 ttl=64 time=7802 ms
64 bytes from 192.168.0.1: icmp_seq=47 ttl=64 time=7349 ms
64 bytes from 192.168.0.1: icmp_seq=48 ttl=64 time=6345 ms
64 bytes from 192.168.0.1: icmp_seq=49 ttl=64 time=5439 ms
64 bytes from 192.168.0.1: icmp_seq=51 ttl=64 time=3499 ms
```

I've tried turn off the power manager, It doesn't work on my machine.
now, the iwconfig reports:

```
wlp4s0    IEEE 802.11  ESSID:"staynoob.cn"  
          Mode:Managed  Frequency:2.462 GHz  Access Point: 24:69:68:94:0E:AE   
          Bit Rate=150 Mb/s   Tx-Power=22 dBm   
          Retry short limit:7   RTS thr:off   Fragment thr:off
          Encryption key:off
          Power Management:off
          Link Quality=58/70  Signal level=-52 dBm  
          Rx invalid nwid:0  Rx invalid crypt:0  Rx invalid frag:0
          Tx excessive retries:6  Invalid misc:127633   Missed beacon:0
```

lshw -class network

```
  *-network                 
       description: Wireless interface
       product: Dual Band Wireless-AC 3168NGW [Stone Peak]
       vendor: Intel Corporation
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:04:00.0
       logical name: wlp4s0
       version: 10
       serial: 7c:b2:7d:89:df:a5
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi pciexpress bus_master cap_list ethernet physical wireless
       configuration: broadcast=yes driver=iwlwifi driverversion=5.0.0-32-generic firmware=29.1044073957.0 ip=192.168.0.102 latency=0 link=yes multicast=yes wireless=IEEE 802.11
       resources: irq:135 memory:df100000-df101fff
```

sudo uname -a:

```
Linux xy-pc 5.0.0-32-generic #34~18.04.2-Ubuntu SMP Thu Oct 10 10:36:02 UTC 2019 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

I have two machine(pc and laptop) running on the same network, both of them have dual os(ubuntu and windows) installed. This problem only occurs in ubuntu system. so I think it's a problem relates to the os.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue and I solved it adding the following line:

```
options iwlwifi 11n_disable=1
```

to this file:

```
/etc/modprobe.d/iwlwifi.conf
```